# How to change table borders style/size/color in HTML

Tags: html, css, colors, html-table, border

Sorry I’m posting this question but at this moment I’m at a dead end.

As you see this Table have different border sizes  and colors, plus the similar situation with cells background is well.

Do anybody can drop me the clue how to make this table in .html ?
What  the table code should look in notepad doc ?
I’m completely get lost in those:  cell spacing="0" cell padding="4",… (and so far and so on).

Maybe just not impossible to create this table in html ?

Well, for skilled programmer this probably sound  pretty funny, but I have no idea how to deal with it, and especially when I have way difficult Tables at my work.

[image]

Comment: Google 'html table maker' and you'll get lot's of free sites to help you out with this.  Here is one [link](http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_generator.cfm) that came up first.

Comment: Unfortunately quackit.com cant help to deal with this ''Size'' problem. Only simple tables in there. =(

Comment: You've got to do a little reading and research and not expect someone to do it all for you.  Here is a good [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html) that explains everything you want to know about formatting tables in html.

Answer (score 1):

You can style each cell. For example:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th class="border-top-blue">1</th>
        <th class="bg-red">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Speed</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td class="bg-yellow border-dotted">200</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the table above I added some CSS classes to the rows:

```
.border-top-blue {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.border-dotted {
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

This way you can change the border, background color, size, etc. Hope You get the point!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the exact colors or widths for your cells, but here's the structure of that table. I know how tricky tables are. I hope this helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/yen9ritch/8vsE4/

HTML

```
    <table id="sampleTable" width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" class="graybg-blackborder" style="border-top: 2px #000 solid;">DAY</td>
    <td class="graybg-blackborder" style="border-top: 2px blue solid; border-left: none;">1</td>
    <td class="redbg-blackborder" style="border-top: 2px #000 solid; border-left: none;">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150" class="graybg-blackborder">Speed</td>
    <td class="dottedBottomBorder rightThinBorder">1.20kb/h</td>
    <td class="dottedBottomBorder rightThinBorder">1.00kb/h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150" class="graybg-blackborder " style="border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;">Total</td>
    <td class="rightThinBorder yellowBg dottedBottomBorder">200</td>
    <td class="rightThinBorder thickBottom">220</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
    #sampleTable {
    text-align:center;
}
.graybg-blackborder {
    background: #ccc;
    border-left: 2px #000 solid;
    border-right: 2px #000 solid;
    border-top: 1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.redbg-blackborder {
    background: red;
    border-left: 2px #000 solid;
    border-right: 2px #000 solid;
    border-top: 1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dottedBottomBorder {
    border-bottom: #000 1px dotted;
}
.rightThinBorder {
    border-right: 1px #000 solid;
}
.yellowBg {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.thickBottom {
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
}
```

Comment: Why mix inline styles and CSS classes?

Comment: @JonP To overwrite some of the borders in the classes. That was an interesting mix of borders combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in the HTML file:

```html
<tr>
    <td class = "class1">text</td>
    <td class = "class2">text</td>
</tr>
```

And then have a CSS file:

```css
    .class1 {
        background-color: red;
        border: solid green 2px;
    }
```

Or you could use the tree structure with child elements [first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) by the way the first column is probably a th rather than a td.